# Work on an Android program with several computers

Tags: android, eclipse, save

I am developing a project from work, but would like to be able to take the project home and continue it. I can't just "open" a project, so what are the settings to save it on one computer, then open it from home, then save it again to work on it from home?

Comment: I use Dropbox for this. Works very well. As long as there is just one developer. If more than one, you'll need some sort of repository.

Comment: I recommend just using github. Commit push -- Then pull when you get home.

Comment: You can open a project. Just use the import wizard in eclipse. File -> Import.. -> Existing Project into Workspace
Although I would recommend a versioning tool like subversion,git or mercurial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using Dropbox or github, I assume you're emailing the code or using a USB drive.  After you've unzipped your project to your other computer's home directory, run Eclipse and do

File, New, Android Project
enter the Project Name
in Contents, select Create project from existing source
in Location, browse to the directory you just created in your home directory
choose a Build Target
and click Finish assuming the other settings have been filled in for you.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com).  My Eclipse workspace is inside my Dropbox folder, so whenever I load up Eclipse on any of my computers, I always have the most updated versions of my files without any hassle.

This also gives you the added benefit of not having to worry about a harddisk failure and being able to rollback files.

Answer (score 2):

Either do as Glendon said or setup a subversion or git repository.
I usually do both.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing by putting a bare git repository on a memory stick and cloning it onto all development machines.

As the repositories on the development machines are cloned from the one on the stick, their "origin" will point back to the memory stick. So all I have to do when bouncing from one development machine to the other is

```
<insert memory stick>
cd <work_directory_on_harddisk>
git pull
...write code
git push
<remove memory stick>
```

and I am done.

What is nice about this is that even if you forget the stick, or forget to synchronize and end up working on an outdated directory, you can untangle it easily with all the power of git.